# Ansible: How to create nested dictionary using Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

Here is the output.

```
"result.containers":[
{
  "Image":"ca.docker/webproxy:1.0.0",
  "Names":[
     "/customer1"
  ]
},
{
  "Image":"docker.local/egacustomer:1.0.1",
  "Names":[
     "/registrator"
  ]
}
]
```

I'm trying to get the following output using jinja2

```
"containerlist"=>{
            "webproxy": {
                "name": "customer1"
           }, 
            "egacustomer": {
                "name": "registrator"
           }
         }
```

Here is my jinja2 code.

```
- set_fact:
      containerlist: |
       {
       {% for item in result.containers %}
       {{ item.Image.split('/')[-1].split(':')[0] | replace('\n', '') }}
            name : {{ item.Names[0][1:] | replace('\n', '') }}
       {% endfor %}
       }
```

I get the below output.

```
 "containerlist": "{\nwebproxy\n     name : customer1\negacustome\n     name : registrator\n}"
```

Could someone please help me get the desired output. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data in YAML

```yaml
  result:
    containers:
      - Image: ca.docker/webproxy:1.0.0
        Names:
          - /customer1
      - Image: docker.local/egacustomer:1.0.1
        Names:
          - /registrator
```

---

The tasks below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        containerlist: "{{ containerlist|default({})|
                           combine({key: {'name': name}}) }}"
      loop: "{{ result.containers }}"
      vars:
        key: "{{ (item.Image.split(':')|first).split('/')|last }}"
        name: "{{ item.Names[0][1:] }}"
    - debug:
        var: containerlist
```

give

```yaml
  containerlist:
    egacustomer:
      name: registrator
    webproxy:
      name: customer1
```

But, the result is not a  list. It's a dictionary. If you want a list use this

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        containerlist: "{{ containerlist|default([]) +
                           [{key: {'name': name}}] }}"
      loop: "{{ result.containers }}"
      vars:
        key: "{{ (item.Image.split(':')|first).split('/')|last }}"
        name: "{{ item.Names[0][1:] }}"
    - debug:
        var: containerlist
```

give

```yaml
  containerlist:
  - webproxy:
      name: customer1
  - egacustomer:
      name: registrator
```